# list index out of range through an array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not sure what's wrong. I assume I have surpassed an array limit perhaps.

```
    def lcs(arr):
      if len(arr) == 0:   # arr of length 0
        return
      sumarr = []
      counter = 0
      sum = 0
      for i in arr:
        if arr[i] > 0:
          sum = sum + arr[i]
        if arr[i] < 0:
          sumarr[counter] = sum
          counter += 1
      print max(sumarr)
```

The error I get is:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        File "<stdin>", line 8, in lcs
      IndexError: list index out of range
```

#

I've modded the code a bit

```
      def lcs(arr):
        if len(arr) == 0:   # arr of length 0
          return
        sumarr = []
        counter = 0
        sum = 0
        for i in arr:
          if i > 0:
            sum = sum + i
          if i < 0:
            sumarr[counter] = sum
            counter += 1
        print max(sumarr)
```

However I'm getting this error

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        File "<stdin>", line 13, in lcs
      ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

I thought I was constantly updating my sumarr[]. How come the error is telling me that I am passing an empty list into max()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `for i in arr`, `i` gets the elements of the array (one at a time), not their indices.  What you want in your example is to replace each `arr[i]` with `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate to go point to right position of the array:

```
   def lcs(arr):
      if len(arr) == 0:   # arr of length 0
        return
      sumarr = []
      counter = 0
      sum = 0
      for count, i in enumerate(arr):
        if arr[count] > 0:
          sum = sum + arr[i]
        if arr[count] < 0:
          sumarr[counter] = sum
          counter += 1
      print max(sumarr)
```

Comment: What's the point of using `enumerate` if the `count` variable is not used? (should have `i` instead of `arr[count]`)